# Old azure push received after installation

Tags: android, azure, google-cloud-messaging

I had a strange case where I had received old push messages just after install on a device ? Do you see what can be the cause ? A push parameter misconfigured ?

Thank you

Comment: This happens on the first install on a device. If I uninstall and reinstall, l don't have the problem.

Comment: I think you need to mark sure that you `register` and `unregister` a device token correctly. Check out [here](https://github.com/google/gcm) for the code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found that campaigns with none duration, created on the azure admin panel, or sent by the api with the real time option, caused the campaign push to be also sent to future users. Using the one-shot option with the api resolved the problem. This option is not present on the azure admin panel which was confusing for me as I was trying to find the good sending criterias using it.